# Overloading operator<< Cannot bind basic_ostream<char> lvalue

Tags: c++

Why is it that this doesn't work :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d)
{
    return os << '(' << d.year() << ',' << d.month();
}
```

while this works :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d)
{
    return os << '(' << d.year() << ',';
}
```

**EDIT** The error :

```
error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Chrono::Month]'|
```

I found some questions about this but their questions were way too advanced and I couldn't understand it.

**Edit 2**

The `month()` function :

```
Month month() const {return m;}
```

And the `Month` `enum class` :

```
enum class Month
{
    jan = 1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov ,dec
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies where you are invoking the `operator<<`, not in its definition.

You are probably calling it in a context like this:

```
std::ofstream() << "Hello World";
```

i.e. you are writing into a *temporary* `ostream`. That is in contrast with the definition of `operator<<`, in which you state that you are using a "*permanent*" (i.e. not a temporary) ostream.

**EDIT**

After a further examination of the error message, the problem came out to be the missing definition of `operator<<` for the type `enum class Month`. Adding such a definition, i.e. `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Month m)`, solved the problem.

Comment: It's merely an implementation I haven't invoked it yet.

Comment: Is it possible that the error happened because of the lack of main()?

Comment: @J.Alvaro.T It sounds strange to me... I'm pretty sure you are calling it somewhere. Can you post a more comprehensive error message, so we can see where the error is?

Comment: @J.Alvaro.T Well, adding the main function sounds like a good idea, but I don't think the error was caused by that

Comment: @J.Alvaro.T Another (remote) possibility is that the error is inside d.month()...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84361/discussion-between-paolo-m-and-j-alvaro-t).

Answer (score 0):

Mine works properly

```
#include <iostream>

class Date
{
private:
    int d, m, y;
public:
    Date(int _d, int _m, int _y) : d(_d), m(_m), y(_y) {}
    int day() const { return d; }
    int month() const { return m; }
    int year() const { return y; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Date &d);
};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Date &d)
{
    return out << '(' << d.year() << ',' << d.month();
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << Date(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it won't compile on mine?

Comment: Well, I'm using the GCC that comes with Code:Blocks could it be the problem?